# Negative user input in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem that may seem trivial, but I have enormous problem working it out myself. Here is my simple code:

```
#include <cstdio> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
    int z; 
    scanf("%d", &z); 
    for(int i = 0; i < z; ++i){ 
        double x0, x1; 
        scanf("%lf %lf", &x0, &x1); 
        printf("%lf %lf", x0, x1); 
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I give program input below:

```
4 
1 7 
4 2 
7 1 
−21 −3
```

I receive this output:

```
1.000000 7.000000 
4.000000 2.000000 
7.000000 1.000000 
7.000000 1.000000
```

It looks like last line isn't read at all. Nevertheless, I did test my program on other data sets and I made some interesting observations:

1) Program has this problem when executed on Ubuntu (checked at my and friend's computer) or ideone.

2) Program doesn't have a problem on Windows (my computer and friend's).

3) Bug might be caused by negative value, but isn't caused by all negative values.

4) Using iostream instead of cstdio doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: The character in your question is − but the minus character is - . Maybe it got changed as the text went through a word processor or something (they can have an annoying habit of doing that). http://ideone.com/CIF1ez

Comment: Get into the habit of building error checking into your code. If your program had output "`scanf` failed" rather than repeating the previously-read data, then you would have very quickly discovered the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` needs the [hyphen-minus character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) with the ASCII code 45 (-).

You accidentally entered the non-ASCII [minus sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Character_codes) (−).

Comment: I've seen this happen with a "smart" text editor. There should be a setting to turn off these substitutions. Find that setting or it will keep happening.